# Apache 2.4 Httpd 403 Forbidden in Vagrant of Centos 7

Tags: apache, vagrant

After `vagrant up` with Centos7 and `httpd` (Apache 2.4) is installed, I test the `testa.dev.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName html.testa.dev
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/testa.dev/htdocs"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/testa.dev/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and it can be accessed as `http://html.test.dev` while

- the domain name is added to `/etc/hosts` in host
- NO change in the default setting `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
- a test page `/var/www/html/testa.dev/htdocs/index.html` is created

***However, when I'm trying to test other directories, it comes to 403 Forbidden.*** What I have done is

to create `testb.dev.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName html.testb.dev
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/testb.dev/htdocs"

    <Directory "/srv/www/testb.dev/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

to create a test page `/srv/www/testb.dev/htdocs/index.html`

to grant permissions by

```
chown -R apache:apache /srv/www/testb.dev/htdocs
chmod -R 755 /srv/www/testb.dev/htdocs
```

My idea is straight forward. Just want to change `/var/www` to `/srv/www`. But it seems there still some configuration around I missed.

Comment: try `setenforce 0`

Comment: You are right. But if going to production, what to do instead of running `setenforce 0` directly?

Comment: You can either permanently [set SELinux to permissive mode](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html) or fix [SELinux contex of the DocumentRoot folder](https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the references.